# Modified Knapsack algorithm

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I've different classes of items. Each item has `value` and `weight`.

For example:

`ClassA: [A1, A2, A3]`

`ClassB: [B1, B2, B3]`

`ClassC: [C1, C2, C3]`

How should I modify classic 0-1 Knapsack problem so that algorithm optimize solution maximizing overall value, consider all items in class but allowed to pick at at most one item from one class?

```
package knapsack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Knapsack {

    private int totalNumberOfItems;
    private int maxmimumKnapsackCapacityUnits;

    private double[][] optimum;
    private boolean[][] solution;

    private double [] value;
    private int [] weight;

    public Knapsack(int knapsackCapacityUnits, List<KnapsackItem> items){

        this.totalNumberOfItems = items.size();
        this.maxmimumKnapsackCapacityUnits = knapsackCapacityUnits;

        this.optimum = new double[items.size() + 1][knapsackCapacityUnits + 1];
        this.solution = new boolean[items.size() + 1][knapsackCapacityUnits + 1];

        this.value = new double[items.size() + 1];
        this.weight = new int[items.size() + 1];

        int index=1;
        for(KnapsackItem item : items){
            value[index] = item.value;
            weight[index] = item.weight;
            index++;
        }


}

public List<KnapsackItem> optimize(){

    for(int currentItem = 1; currentItem <= totalNumberOfItems; currentItem++){
        for(int currentWeightUnit = 1; currentWeightUnit <= maxmimumKnapsackCapacityUnits; currentWeightUnit++){

            double option1 = optimum[currentItem - 1][currentWeightUnit];

            double option2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

            if(weight[currentItem] <= currentWeightUnit){
                option2 = value[currentItem] + optimum[currentItem-1][currentWeightUnit - weight[currentItem]];
            }

            optimum[currentItem][currentWeightUnit] = Math.max(option1, option2);
            solution[currentItem][currentWeightUnit] = (option2 > option1);
        }
    }

    boolean take [] = new boolean[totalNumberOfItems + 1];
    for(int currentItem = totalNumberOfItems,
            currentWeightUnit = maxmimumKnapsackCapacityUnits; 
            currentItem > 0; currentItem --){
        if(solution[currentItem][currentWeightUnit]){
            take[currentItem] = true;
            currentWeightUnit = currentWeightUnit - weight[currentItem];
        }
        else{
            take[currentItem] = false;
        }
    }

    List<KnapsackItem> items = new ArrayList<KnapsackItem>();
    for(int i = 0; i < take.length; i++){
        KnapsackItem newItem = new KnapsackItem();
        newItem.value = value[i];
        newItem.weight = weight[i];
        newItem.isTaken = take[i];
        items.add(newItem);
    }

    return items;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic algorithm goes like:

```
for i in items:
    for w in possible total weights (downwards):
        if w is achievable with maximum value v:
            (w + weight[i]) is also achievable with at least value (v + value[i])
```

The approach here will be a slight variation of that:

```
for c in classes:
    for w in possible total weights (downwards):
        if w is achievable with maximum value v:
            for i in items of class c:
                (w + weight[i]) is also achievable with at least value (v + value[i])
```

---

With your code, the changes would be the following:

1. Perhaps you will want to make a separate list of items for each class. In line with what is currently done, I'd expect `value` and `weight` to become lists of lists, and some variable and array named like `numberOfClasses` and `numberOfClassItems` to monitor the lengths of the new lists.
   For example, suppose two class 1 items are (w=2,v=3) and (w=3,v=5), and three class 2 items are (w=1,v=1), (w=4,v=1) and (w=1,v=4). Then we will have:
   `totalNumberOfItems = 5`,
   `numberOfClasses = 2`,
   `numberOfClassItems = [2, 3]`,
   `value  = [[3, 5], [1, 1, 4]]` and
   `weight = [[2, 3], [1, 4, 1]]`.
   That is if you index from `0`.  Indexing from `1` as you do will leave unused zeroes or empty lists at the start of each list.
2. The `for (currentItem)` loop will become a `for (currentClass)` loop. The arrays `optimum` and `solution` will be indexed by `currentClass` instead of `currentItem`.
3. The value `option2` will in fact be calculated as the best of several options, one per class item:

   `double option2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   for (currentItem = 1; currentItem <= numberOfClassItems[currentClass];
        currentItem++){
       if(weight[currentClass][currentItem] <= currentWeightUnit){
           option2 = Math.max (option2, value[currentClass][currentItem] +
                     optimum[currentClass - 1][currentWeightUnit -
                                               weight[currentClass][currentItem]]);
       }
   }`
4. Perhaps the `solution` array should now contain `int` instead of `boolean`: the number of item of this class which we take, or some sentinel value (`0` or `-1`) if we take `option1` and don't use any item of this class.

Comment: thanks for reply! If I understood correctly in your modified version of algorithm you are checking weight of item against maximum capacity `if w is achievable with maximum value v:` but that happens before you iterating through class items. So I am not sure how that suppose to work. I've included my code, so maybe my algo is a bit different and you could take a look what I've done. Thanks!

Comment: @WildGoat: I added some pointers to what effect this approach can have on your code.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am trying to understand your solution and make changes to my existing code. I will let you know how it is going. Thanks for such constructive answer!

Answer (score 0):

The approach to solve this problem is to consider classes `A,B,C` as items themselves and then proceed to make the choices in the individual class to select the best out of them.

```
number of items = number of classes = N
Knapsack capacity  = W
Let item[i][k] be kth item of ith class.
```

**simple DP solution to problem with simple modification to knapsack solution :-**

```
int DP[n][W+1]={0};

//base condition for item = 0

for(int i=0;i<=W;i++) {

   for(int j=0;j<item[0].size();j++) {
         if(i>=item[0][j].weight) {
              DP[0][i] = max(DP[0][i],item[0][j].value);
         }
   }

} 

//Actual DP 

for(int k=0;k<=W;k++) {

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {  

    for(int j=0;j<item[i].size();j++) {
         if(k>=item[i][j].weight) {
              DP[i][k] = max(DP[i][k],DP[i-1][k-item[i][j].weight]+item[i][j].value);
         }
     }

     DP[i][k] = max(DP[i][k],DP[i-1][k]);

  }

}

print("max value : ",DP[n-1][W]);
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work? For starters, there is no single "best" item in a class. For example, a class may contain an item of weight 3 and value 5, and another item of weight 5 and value 8. You don't know in advance which one is "better" when you have limited capacity.

Comment: @Gassa this being a DP we are not deciding in advance but selecting each item from a class individually and checking the result and selecting the item which gives the maximum weight for particular sub-problem . It is similar to original knapsack problem but only one or none of the items from a class are considered . Can you plz tell me what u didnt get from the pseudo code

Comment: Sorry, I found the text ("selecting the best item from a class") confusing: it reads to me like "there is a single best item in each class". So, I didn't give much thought to the code. Now that I read the code, it seems to do the right thing.

Comment: @VikramBhat, Do you have any idea about this one - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415617? Thank You.